# How to include an ampersand (&) in the content of a ComboBoxItem

Tags: xaml, escaping

I currently have a Combobox like the following:

```
//XAML
<ComboBox>
<ComboBoxItem> Awake & Alive</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This raises an error: 
Entity references or sequences beginning with an ampersand '&' must be terminated with a semicolon ';'.

I assume I am missing an escape sequence of some sort to allow me to use a &. How can I set the content of this comboboxitem to include a &?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Use `&amp;` to encode the ampersand.

```
//XAML
<ComboBox>
<ComboBoxItem> Awake &amp; Alive</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 23):

The short answer is to use `&amp;` to *encode* an ampersand.

See also [Entities: Handling Special Content](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html) on XML.com:

> At the lowest levels an XML parser is just a program that reads through an XML document a character at a time and analyzes it in one way or another, then behaves accordingly. It knows that it's got to process some content differently than other content. What distinguishes these special cases is the presence of such characters as "`&`" and "`<`". They act as flags to the parser; they delimit the document's actual content, alerting the parser to the fact that it must do something at this point other than simply pass the adjacent content to some downstream application.
>
> ... So one way to get around your immediate problem is to replace the ampersand in your content with the appropriate entity reference: `<company>Harris &amp; George</company>`.

Comment: I have corrected the terminology (encode vs. escape) in my answer.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Your link has useful comparisons for >, <, " and '. See the table starting with "Entity reference  Stands for..."

Comment: Thats a grt answer :) thnx :)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can use the CDATA tag around the contents of the ComboBoxItem element; I think it better maintains the text's readability.

```
//XAML
<ComboBox>
<ComboBoxItem><![CDATA[Awake & Alive]]></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp