# Ampersand in WPF Binding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-4.0

I'm trying to create a string format that has a literal string containing an ampersand. I've tried & and & amp; (without the space) but both cause an exception in the VS2010 designer. Here's what I'm working with:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LearningOpportunities, StringFormat='Sharing & Learning Opportunitites:\{0\}'}"
```

If I use '&', it tells me "Entity references or sequences beginning with an ampersand '&' must be terminated with a semicolon ';'". If I use & amp;, it gets a FormatException: "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list." I've been doing web development away from WPF for a while so I'm feeling a little rusty. How can I get this working?

Edit: There's been a lot of speculation regarding escaping being the culprit and from what I can tell, it's all incorrect. So to get that out of the way here's what works and doesn't work, taking the ampersand out of the equation:

**Formats that work:**

```
StringFormat=Sharing and learning opportunitites:\{0\}
StringFormat='Sharing and learning opportunitites:\{0\}'
StringFormat={}Sharing and learning opportunitites:{0}
StringFormat='{}Sharing and learning opportunitites:{0}'
StringFormat=Sharing and learning opportunitites:{0}
StringFormat='Sharing and learning opportunitites:{0}'
```

**Formats that don't work:**

```
StringFormat=Sharing and learning opportunitites:{}{0}
StringFormat=Sharing and learning opportunitites:{{0}}  (Outputs literal "{0}")
```

So to summarize, you can escape all braces in the string by placing opening and closing braces {} at the *beginning* of the string, or you can escape individual braces using backslashes. Surprisingly, it still worked without escaping the braces, but the syntax coloring was pretty ugly in Visual Studio. To avoid ugly syntax coloring, you can use single quotes around the format string.

So with escaping put to rest, the problem is that adding an ampersand to the format string causes an exception, whether it is escaped or not. The only difference between escaped and not escaped is it gives a different exception.

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908761/how-to-include-an-ampersand-in-the-content-of-a-comboboxitem

Comment: Hmmm. Add the code where you're trying to do the format call - there's something else afoot.

Comment: Edited to show I've already tried escaped ampersand. @JerKimball, that is the code above.

Comment: Ah, I see...try this? StringFormat=Foo &amp; Bar: {}{0}

Comment: Interesting, that does it. It was acting like it would get an exception the second I even type a '&', but this works. Thanks! If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @xr280xr Glad to help - and don't give up, WPF is a bit tricky coming from the web, but you'll see a lot of strange similarities between XAML and HTML...

Comment: @JerKimball I'm confused. Your suggestion appeared as Foo &amp;amp; before, and that was what I said worked. However, I've now discovered that it gets rid of the error but the end result is that it outputs "&amp;" in my string. So this is still unsolved.

Comment: @xr280xr Grr...I hate fiddling with markdown syntax...one sec, let me see if I can cobble together a full example and I'll add it in to my answer.

Comment: @xr280xr There, it seems like it posted correctly that time - give those a whirl?

Comment: @JerKimball I'm surprised `StringFormat=Foo &amp; Bar: {}{0}` is working for you... Are you using that in an actual binding, like `{Binding SomeString, StringFormat=Foo &amp; Bar: {}{0}}`? It does not work for me. I have to put the `{}` at the front of the entire string, not just in front of the value, like I have in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618610/302677). But I think different syntaxes might work with different version of WPF.

Comment: @Rachel Yeah, they all work :) - FWIW, I'm on WindowsBase/PresentationCore v4.0.30319 (Oh, windows 7 as well)

Comment: @rachel - Just in case the editor is still mucking around with things, I've added a pastebin link as well.

Comment: Stupid designer bugs...tell you what, I'm favoriting this one so I can reference it in the future...one of these days I'll see if there is a way to monkey patch the faulting code somehow on the designer side. Thanks for the interesting diversion! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITEDITEDIT:

Aha! Turns out to be a bloody bug with the Cider design surface!

Proof:

Try this sequence of XAML lines:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- should show '$YoMamma' -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x24;{0}}"/>
    <!-- should show '%YoMamma' -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x25;{0}}"/>
    <!-- should show '&YoMamma', but crashes the designer -->
    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x26;{0}}"/>-->
    <!-- should show '"YoMamma', but crashes the designer -->
    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x27;{0}}"/>-->
    <!-- should show '(YoMamma' -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x28;{0}}"/>
    <!-- should show ')YoMamma' -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=&#x29;{0}}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

I submitted a bug report to connect, we'll see if anyone responds:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782059/cider-vs2010-designer-bug-with-binding-using-escaped-entities-in-stringformat

Rest of this answer is semi-moot, albeit potentially useful, since the "bug" is on the designer.

The thing to remember here is that XAML **is** XML, so you need to encode ampersands accordingly:

```
&amp;
```

should work, as well as:

```
&#38;
```

EDIT:

Ah, yes - so as discussed in the back-and-forth in the comments, the problem lay not with the ampersand *per se*, but the "escaping" of the replacement markers within the surrounding braces of a `Binding` - to fix this, you've actually got three options:

EDIT 2: Bah, I think markdown might not like my post (and I was wrong on one point anyway) - let's see if I can cobble a full example together:

Just in case, here's a pastebin link as well:
http://pastebin.com/yfrpvxs1

So say we've got a context object like so:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; FireNpc("Value"); }
    }
    private decimal _numberValue;
    public decimal NumberValue
    {
        get { return _numberValue; }
        set { _numberValue = value; FireNpc("NumberValue"); }
    }
    private DateTime _dateValue;
    public DateTime DateValue
    {
        get { return _dateValue; }
        set { _dateValue = value; FireNpc("DateValue"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void FireNpc(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

And a window codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Foo()
            {
                Value = "YoMamma", 
                DateValue = DateTime.Now, 
                NumberValue = 3.14m
            };
    }
}
```

Let's XAML!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- should show '#1:Foo & Bar:YoMamma' -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=#1:Foo &amp; Bar:{0}}"/>

        <!-- should show '#2:Foo & Bar:YoMamma' -->
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="Value" StringFormat="#2:Foo &amp; Bar:{0}"/>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>

        <!-- will actually show the '{' and '}', so 'Foo & Bar:{0}' -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=Foo &amp; Bar:{{0}}}"/>

        <!-- default 'custom' (there's a fun oxymoron) format - should be '$3.14' -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NumberValue, StringFormat=c}"/>

        <!-- custom 'custom' (bear with me) format -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateValue, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}"/>

        <!-- multi parameter formatting-->
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="As of {2:MM/dd/yyyy}, {0} cost {1:c}">
                    <Binding Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding Path="NumberValue"/>
                    <Binding Path="DateValue"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now, piggybacking on that `MultiBinding`, we can do something stupid - let's add this to our context:

```
    // Heh...don't actually do this, naturally...
    private string _ampersandValue;
    public string AmpersandValue
    {
        get { return _ampersandValue; }
        set { _ampersandValue = value; FireNpc("AmpersandValue"); }
    }


    this.DataContext = new Foo()
        {
            Value = "YoMamma", 
            DateValue = DateTime.Now, 
            NumberValue = 3.14m,
            AmpersandValue = "&"
        };
```

And add this XAML:

```
    <!-- And a crazy-person's method, using multi parameter formatting-->
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {0} = {0}">
                <Binding Path="Value"/>
                <Binding Path="AmpersandValue"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Editor messed with my post. I tried to write that I tried that already.

Comment: Thanks for the entertaining answer. But have you tried it out? The ampersand (first char of &amp;) in the first and third TextBlocks cause an exception for me: "System.FormatException
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Comment: @xr280xr - yeah, all that is straight up copypasta from a wpf app I just threw together; it displayed just as expected...you got that error with this code??

Comment: Yep, copied and pasted into a test project. Using VS 2010, and .NET Framework 4

Comment: @xr280xr Ooh, things are getting interesting then...how about that pastebin link I added?

Comment: Same result. In both my real project and test project, the second I type an ampersand character into the format string, it blows up. The only way I've been able to have an '&' character in the format string without it blowing up is using "&amp;amp;", which results in the string "&amp;" being displayed. Not very useful, but maybe a clue. Very strange that it works for you and not me. That was what I expected to work originally before posting this question.

Comment: @xr280xr Oh wait - the **designer** is blowing up as soon as you type that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26879/discussion-between-jerkimball-and-xr280xr)

Comment: So bottom line: Either use the inline syntax at the cost of the designer blowing up (but it will still work at run time), or use the complete binding syntax to retain designer support. Major props to JerKimball!

Comment: @xr280xr Hah - did find one thing that might work...an alternate ampersand character: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=A &#xff06; B:{0}}"/>`

Comment: For the "Fullwidth ampersand" unicode character, nice. Since that's technically a different character, you could also put it directly in the markup without having to escape it. Seems like it could be problematic between different fonts though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&amp;` for the ampersand, and remove the `\` which are acting as escape characters.  You also have extra `'` characters which aren't required.  Try the following:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LearningOpportunities, StringFormat=Sharing &amp; Learning Opportunitites:{0}}"
```

Comment: @xr280xr Edited - the problem was a mix of not using `&amp;` and also putting extra `\` characters in...

Comment: I think Reed's on the right line of thought: I think it's the braces that are messing you up, not the ampersand; check the comment I added on op

Comment: Btw to Reed: root cause actually a designer bug; fun fun fun...and something to note in that reference manual of a brain you've got ;)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I want to use `StringFormat` in the binding, and my format contains additional text or spaces, I put an extra set of curley braces at the front like this:

```
StringFormat={}Sharing and learning opportunitites:{0}
```

I know I've seen references online using other methods, but they've all failed me at one time or another. I think different versions of WPF support different `StringFormat` syntaxes, so depending on what version you're using, other syntax may work as well, however the above is the only one I've found to be fairly universal.

Also, you'll want to use `&amp;` to escape the `&` character

```
StringFormat={}Sharing &amp; learning opportunitites:{0}
```